# Convert url parameters using Refit

Tags: c#, xamarin, refit

I am using the [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) library to access my API. This is working quite good, but i have some problems using a list of enums in my url.

```
[Get("/track/")]
Task<IList<Track>> GetAll(int size = 20, int from = 0, [AliasAs("content-types")] IEnumerable<TrackSubType> contentTypes = null, IEnumerable<string> tags = null, string language = null);
```

The IEnumerable contentTypes is currently converted to:

```
https://website.com/track/?content-type=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Api.Implementation.Models.TrackSubType]
```

I want to have it in the format:

```
https://website.com/track/?content-type[]=sometype
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is currently not possible with Refit without doing some workarounds. There is an issue in GitHub of Refit where this topic is covered and there is someone working on it: https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/issues/4

Answer (score 2):

I believe Refit by default uses ToString on your list to create the query parameter value. You could create your own class inheriting from list and override the ToString method to achieve what you want at the right side of the equals sign. I'm not so sure about why you cannot add the square brackets using the aliasas attribute though.